# Mapping Typescript dynamic types into Java Object's subclasses

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Typescript model being sent as JSON request to my back end server. I can't change the model into a more engineered format, so I have to use what the client is going to send me.

The Typescript interface uses the pipe to perform polymorphism as shown below:

```js
export interface Field {
  align: 'center' | 'left'; // css property that does not work  disabled: boolean;
  label: string;
  readonly: boolean;
  ref: string; // unique identifier  size: string; // css width  type: FIELD_TYPES;
  value: string;
  required: boolean;
  visible: string; // 'true' | 'plugin:...'  
  invisible: 'true' | 'false'; // never used  
  optional: string; // just in 3 fields, never used 
  option:
    | string // 'plugin:...'    
    | { value: string; label: string; disable?: string; labelEng?: string, valueOfAnswerInInterestType?: string }[] //FieldOption
    | { 1?: string; 2?: string; 3?: string; 4?: string; 5?: string; 6?: string };  //Map<Integer,String>
}
```

As you can see, `option` can either be `String` or an array, or a plain POJO.

What I need to achieve is to create a Jackson mapping and use Java's powerful `instanceof` operator to work on the deserialized class.

Look at this target model:

```java
@Data
public class Field {    
    private DetFieldAlignment align; // css property that does not work  disabled: boolean;    
    ....
    private String optional;//  just in 3 fields, never used    
   
    private Object option; // 'plugin:...' | [{ value: 1, label: 'my value' }, ...] | { "1": "Option one ..."}
}

@Data
public class DetFieldOption {
    private String value;
    private String label;
    private String disable;
    ....
}
```

I need to instruct Jackson about polymorphic serialization for the possible subclasses of `Object`, but I am having difficulty.
I wrote JUnit tests to validate the result (`option instanceof String` vs check that every item in list is `instanceof FieldOption`) but obviously it's not working.

With the above model, a `String` is recognized in my test payload, but the array of `FieldOption` translated into an array of `LinkedHashMap`s

Without yet working on the case of `Map<Integer,String>`, I have tried to add the following polymorphic annotations to `Object option` field

```java
 @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)    
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(String.class),            
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(FieldOption.class)     
    })
```

It does not work with the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subtypes java.lang.String and java.lang.Object have the same signature and cannot be uniquely deduced.
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.buildFingerprints(AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java:89)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.<init>(AsDeductionTypeDeserializer.java:48)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.StdTypeResolverBuilder.buildTypeDeserializer(StdTypeResolverBuilder.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findPropertyTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:2022)
    ... 89 more
```

I can't control the payload coming from the front end, which means I can't ask the FE developers to add a type indication in the payload, especially considering that the object could be a String.

### Question

How can I define a polymorphic serialization that deserializes into either:

- java.lang.String
- java.util.Collection
- java.util.Map<Integer,String>

Of course, I don't expect keys to be other than integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to encapsulate a polymorphic value into the `Object`field of your `Field` class the task can be solved with a custom [`StdDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) deserializer distinguishing the three cases you indicated (string, array, and map). So if you take a simplified version of your classes like below:

```
@Data
public class Field {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OptionDeserializer.class)
    private Object option;
}

@Data
public class DetFieldOption {
    private String value;
    private String label;
}
```

You can define a custom `stdDeserializer` that can return a different object in the three cases you indicated checking if the `JsonNode` option is a string, an array, or an object:

```
public class OptionDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Object> {

    public OptionDeserializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
        //jsonnode is an array so it will be converted to DetFieldOption[]
        if (node.isArray()) {
            return codec.treeToValue(node, DetFieldOption[].class);
        }
        //jsonnode is a pojo so to convert it to a Map<String, String>
        //it is necessary to define a new TypeReference
        //no key as Integer because in a json keys are always string
        //but you can convert them to integer if you need
        if (node.isObject()) {
            TypeReference typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){};
            Map<String, String> map = codec.readValue(codec.treeAsTokens(node),
                    dc.getTypeFactory().constructType(typeRef));
            return map;
        }
        //default case node is a string
        return node.asText();
    }
}
```

Then you can convert json strings like the following below to `Field` objects:

```
String json3 = """
                    {"option": "myString"}
              """;

String json2 = """
                    {"option": [{"value": "myValue"}]}
               """;
String json3 = """
                    {"option": {"1": "myString1"}}
               """;
Field field1 = mapper.readValue(json1, Field.class);
Field field2 = mapper.readValue(json2, Field.class);
Field field3 = mapper.readValue(json3, Field.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. I used Spring Boot's [`ObjectDeserializer<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonObjectDeserializer.html) but the approach is the same